# Dependent destroy not working for STI class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

I am facing Issue when trying to destroy using nested attribute for STI classes in rails 4. 
eg:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class B < A
  has_many :options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

When I try to delete the options its not being deleted event it is has `marked_for_destruction?` as `true`, but the option is not being deleted.

I have all correct paramaters accessible like `:id, :name, :_destroy`.

Comment: debug. add `binding.pry` to the place, where  you delete the option, and see, what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it working by moving nested attributes code and has_many to base class.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :options
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options, :allow_destroy => true
end

class B < A

end
```

I think its issue with STI in rails same as you can not update the type of the STI class object(there is workaround fix for that).